How do I get code for a function when internally `mapply(FUN=FUN, ...)` is called; specifically the function `distributionsrd::qdoubleparetolognormal`
tldr; I would like the mathematical expressions used to calculate the quantiles of the double pareto lognormal in the distributionsrd package, function qdoubleparetolognormal. Internally mapply(FUN=FUN,...) is being called and I don't see any math or where FUN is defined.
I have successfully used the copula package to fit a normal copula with double pareto log normal marginals (using the dparetolognormal and pparetolognormal functions in the distributionsrd package; note I had to slightly rearrange the calculations within these functions to prevent numerical overflow [combining exponentials]). In trying to generate random numbers using the function rMvdc, I am getting the error
Error in uniroot(function(q, shape1, shape2, meanlog, sdlog, p) { :    no sign change found in 1000 iterations
I see internally that rMvdc is calling qdoubleparetolognormal. I would like to see where qdoubleparetolognormal calls uniroot, so I print the function code and get
> qdoubleparetolognormal
function (p, shape1 = 1.5, shape2 = 1.5, meanlog = -0.5, sdlog = 0.5, 
    lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) 
{
    args <- lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1L], eval, parent.frame())
    names <- if (is.null(names(args))) 
        character(length(args))
    else names(args)
    dovec <- names %in% vectorize.args
    do.call("mapply", c(FUN = FUN, args[dovec], MoreArgs = list(args[!dovec]), 
        SIMPLIFY = SIMPLIFY, USE.NAMES = USE.NAMES))
}
<bytecode: 0x00000224fdf267f0>
<environment: 0x00000224fdf1f460>

I was wondering what FUN=FUN is doing, because there is no variable called FUN in the workspace. So looked into the mapply documentation:
FUN     function to apply, found via match.fun.

My guess is that FUN=FUN uses match.fun() to call qdoubleparetolognormal again? But I am confused on how to get the internal code that qdoubleparetolognormal is using in this final step (after match.fun() has been called). How can I get the function definition that actually does the math?

What other internal code? There is no other internal code apart from what you see. Ohh and what exactly is FUN?

and why do you want that? what is your objective??

I edited the question to expand. I don't know what FUN is... it isn't defined in the workspace. I believe it uses match.fun() to call the parent function call (qdoubleparetolognormal), but I am unsure. My objective is to get the mathematical expressions that calculate quantiles of the double pareto lognormal. That code is clearly not in the function definition posted in the question.

So in short you want to compute the qdoubleparetolognormal without the use of the function qdoubleparetolognormal?

Why do you want to understand the function? just write your own function

I would like to use the function if possible, but the math is not being displayed for me to check for numerical overflow, etc.

The function uses root finding algorithm. I could write a simpler one for you

Thank you Onyambu, the function you wrote does indeed solve the problem. From my question, you can see uniroot is being called which is then giving me an error, just as you used uniroot in your function. My question boils down to where is uniroot actually in the function definition for qdoubleparetolognormal?

Uniroot is a function in stats package that you can access. Its not in the package

check https://github.com/cran/distributionsrd/blob/master/R/doubleparetolognormal.R/#L120 for the function definition

I understand uniroot is not in the distributionsrd package. Thank you for the link! you can see uniroot is in the qdoubleparetolognormal function code. However, why can't I access the code that uses uniroot (the code on the github link) through R when I print out qdoubleparetolognormal? Is it accessible in R like this at all? That's my real question.

You an access the code. consider using debuging and call FUN

Thank you Onyambu. I copied the function code (in the question, the one with mapply not the one on github). I added browser() to the first line. I try to print out FUN and the variable is not found. I also get an error with the if... else part of the code. How can I debug as you suggest? What do you get when you call FUN after using browser()?

Do not add browser. Just use debug. Eg debug(qdoubleparetolognormal) then run qdoubleparetolognormal(0.1) then run each line at a time until you get to mapply then type FUN

I do not know what you are trying to accomplish. The mapply function is just there for vectorization. It has nothing to do with solving the problem. Here is a function that accomplishes what you want:
my_qdoubleparetolognormal1 <- function (p, shape1 = 1.5, shape2 = 1.5, meanlog = -0.5, sdlog = 0.5, 
          lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE){
  p <- if(log.p) exp(p) else p
  p <- if (lower.tail) p else  1 - p
  fn <- \(q) pdoubleparetolognormal(q, shape1, shape2, meanlog, sdlog) - p
  uniroot(fn, interval = c(1e-06, 1), extendInt = "yes")$root
}


Note that the function above does at times give warnings as extend = Yes.
my_qdoubleparetolognormal1(0.1)
[1] 0.1723352
qdoubleparetolognormal(0.1) # one from the package
[1] 0.1723352

The function is not vectorized. Thats why they use mapply to accomplish the vectorization. We will use mapply
my_qdoubleparetolognormal_vec <- function (p, shape1 = 1.5, shape2 = 1.5, meanlog = -0.5, sdlog = 0.5, 
                                           lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE){
  
  mapply(my_qdoubleparetolognormal1, p, shape1, shape2, meanlog, sdlog, lower.tail, log.p)
}


Compare the function to the inbuilt one:
x <- seq(0.1,0.9,0.1)
my_qdoubleparetolognormal_vec(x)
[1] 0.1723352 0.2783234 0.3781708 0.4841963 0.6065086 0.7598161 0.9727864 1.3217682 2.1345231

qdoubleparetolognormal(x)
[1] 0.1723352 0.2783234 0.3781708 0.4841963 0.6065086 0.7598161 0.9727864 1.3217682 2.1345231
 

